# Enable 301 Redirection rule in gatsby website hosted on netlify

Tags: javascript, redirect, gatsby, netlify

I have one issue with the 301 redirection rule. I have built a website with gatsby and hosted it on netlify.

I have used `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes` to remove the trailing slash. It however doesn't redirect with 301 status, instead it redirects with 200 status

For example, if I open xyz.com/pricing/ → it returns 200, instead of 301. ( I want only one URL i.e it should auto redirect to xyz.com/pricing [ without trailing slash ] )

Here I want to make sure it returns 301 in the network tab. A 301 redirect indicates the permanent moving of a web page from one location to another. This way Google will delete the /pricing/ from ranking and we will be left with only one page /pricing. Right now it is treating both the pages different

1. /pricing
2. /pricing/

How can I route all my /prcing/ -> /pricing with 301 redirection?

Here is the setting of my netlify hosting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't (on the 3rd of August of 2021). According to [Netlify's docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#trailing-slash):

> What this means for your redirect rules is that Netlify will match
> paths to rules regardless of whether or not they contain a trailing
> slash
>
> You cannot use a redirect rule to add or remove a trailing slash.

In other words: to optimize and maximize the cache hit rate, Netlify interprets the URLs with and without trailing slash in the same way so the redirecting rules won't have any effect.

```
# These rules are effectively the same:
# either rule alone would trigger on both paths
/blog/title-with-a-typo    /blog/typo-free-title
/blog/title-with-a-typo/   /blog/typo-free-title

# This rule will cause an infinite redirect
# because the paths are effectively the same
/blog/remove-my-slashes/   /blog/remove-my-slashes  301!
```

However, according to [Remove trailing slash in Netlify URLs](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056349113-Remove-trailing-slash-in-Netlify-URLs) (Gatsby's article), the `301` redirection is sometimes performed by default. Try playing with asset optimization and pretty URLs options.